# How do you create a confirmation message in .net Core 2.1 RazorPages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Hopefully not a dumb question- I am rewriting an app from .net core mvc to .net core Razor. In MVC I use viewbags to create and display confirmation of actions being successful or display error message if not. Viewbags don't seem to be used or available in the same way for Razor pages in .net core 2.1.

How do you achieve the above in Razor pages? Any code snippets as example would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Add a property to your page view model and use that ?

Comment: What HTTP method triggers the confirmation or error? For instance, does the end-user action create a POST/PUT/GET/Other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use a [Post-Redirect-Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern to display a message after an action.

Here is an example that uses [`TempData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tempdata) to store a message during a POST and then redirects to a GET. Using `TempData` to store the message is particularly appropriate for redirection, because the data only exists until something reads it.

**SomePage.cshtml**

```
@page
@model SomePageModel

@if(TempData[SomePageModel.MessageKey] is string message) 
{
    <p>@message</p>
} 

<form method="POST">
    <button type="submit">POST!</button>
</form>
```

**SomePage.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace temp.Pages
{
    public class SomePageModel : PageModel
    {
        public const string MessageKey = nameof(MessageKey);

        public void OnGet() { }

        public IActionResult OnPost() {
            TempData[MessageKey] = "POST Success!";
            return RedirectToAction(Request.Path); // redirect to the GET
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern also works for HTTP methods such as PUT and DELETE. Simply substitute any other HTTP verb; for instance, we can do a Put-Redirect-Get.